# ODBC Connection to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, odbc, ado

I'm trying to establish a connection to MS SQL Server using ODBC from MS Excel.

When I attempt to connect via VBA i receive a `Server is not found or not accessible` error.

[image]

The details of my connection as viewed from SQL Server Management Studio 2012 are shown in the picture below.  (To access this connection, I VPN into the network, then do a remote desktop connection into the server machine using my windows credentials.)

[image]

In My VBA connection string I have tried all of the following and they all produce the same error.  What's the appropriate way to build this connection string?

```
Public Const connString1 = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};" _
                    & "server=SBCG-DW.semlerbrossy.com;" _
                    & "database=competitive_data;" _
                    & "Uid=rgrady; Pwd=MYPWD;"
Public Const connString2 = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};" _
                    & "server=SBCG-DW.semlerbrossy.com;" _
                    & "database=competitive_data;" _
                    & "Uid=SEMLERBROSSY\RGrady; Pwd=MYPWD;"
Public Const connString3 = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};" _
                    & "server=192.168.168.254;" _
                    & "database=competitive_data;" _
                    & "Uid=rgrady; Pwd=MYPWD;"
Public Const connString4 = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};" _
                    & "server=[SERVER IP ADDRESS];" _
                    & "database=competitive_data;" _
                    & "Uid=SEMLERBROSSY\RGrady; Pwd=MYPWD;"
Public Const connString5 = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};" _
                    & "server=SBCG-DW\SBCG_SQL_DB;" _
                    & "database=competitive_data;"
```

Comment: Are you running Excel on your PC, VPNed into the remote network? You'll need to use SQL authentication rather than Windows authentication in that case and port 1433 will need to be allowed through the VPN connection.

Comment: Check SQL Server Configuration Manager.. TCP/IP, Named Pipes, Service if enabled and running